# ThreadPoolExecutor and as_completed: does it wait for all futures to complete?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a use case where I need to process several "Task" objects. These Tasks objects are basically web crawlers. Whenever a Task finishes, I'd like to restart it asap, with the same parameters.

This is what I have now:

```
tasks = create_collection_tasks()

with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(tasks)) as executor:
    # Maps the future to a collection task. The mapping is in this direction bc
    # later on we can only iterate over the completed futures.
    futures_to_tasks = {
        executor.submit(task.callback, task.data): task for task in tasks
    }

    while futures_to_tasks:
        for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures_to_tasks):
            # If the future raised an exception, calling result() will re-raise
            try:
                future.result()
            except Exception:
                logger.exception("Collection task failed")

            # When the future is done (completed or crashed/cancelled), put it back
            # in the 'queue' to re-run it
            task = futures_to_tasks.pop(future)
            futures_to_tasks[executor.submit(task.callback, task.data)] = task
```

I have read the doc for `as_completed`: https://docs.python.org/3/library/concurrent.futures.html#concurrent.futures.as_completed, however its behaviour is still not clear to me. Right now, I don't know if `as_completed` takes a "snapshot" of the futures that were in `futures_to_tasks` when it was called and waits for all these futures to complete before finishing the loop, of if it just goes through the futures and yields the ones that were completed, without waiting for the other ones. I'd rather have the later behaviour.

Could you give me a hand please?

Comment: Your description seems to suggest that these tasks run forever. Is there no logic for stopping them?

Comment: The tasks are indeed supposed to run forever, or until I kill them manually.

Comment: It yields them one by one in order of completion

Comment: And as soon as they are completed

Answer (score -1):

Let's assume that you want this run indefinitely (which seems to be implied in your question). You could consider this pattern (explanation follows code):

```
from concurrent.futures import ThreadPoolExecutor
from time import sleep

def trun(v):
    print(v)
    sleep(0.5)

with ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
    tasks = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
    futures = dict()
    while True:
        sleep(0.5)
        for i, t in enumerate(tasks):
            if (f := futures.get(i, None)) is not None:
                if not f.running():
                    print(f'Thread {i} has finished. Awaiting result')
                    f.result()
                    print(f'Restarting thread {i}')
                else:
                    print(f'Thread {i} still running')
                    continue
            else:
                print(f'Starting new thread {i}')
            futures[i] = executor.submit(trun, t)
```

We have a number of tasks represented by the strings in the *tasks* list.

We construct a dictionary the keys of which will be the index of the task and the associated value will be a Future object. In this particular case we could use the values from the list as keys but that may not be appropriate in the real world.

There are hard-coded delays just to simulate real work. You'd need to think about how long a thread would run for in reality to determine if you would need delays in production (to avoid thrashing in the *while* loop).

Enumerate the tasks and check to see if there's a reference to the task id (the list index) in our dictionary. If there is, check to see if it's still running. If it has, fetch the result.

Everything else should be self-explanatory.

This code is runnable but you'll need to stop it manually (Ctrl-C would be ideal)

You could consider using some form of sentinel that would be set in a thread to indicate completion and that could be checked in the main loop. However, there's a potential race condition if handled naively